# Matlab plot interpolated values on the same graph with other curves

Tags: matlab

```
>>a = [0, pi, pi/4, pi/8, pi, 3/(pi*2)]
>>b = cos(a);
>>x = linspace(0,pi,40)';
>>y1 = interp1(a,b,x,'nearest');
>>y2 = interp1(a,b,x,'linear');
>>y3 = interp1(a,b,x,'spline');
>>y4 = interp1(a,b,x,'pchip');
```

How can I plot the four curves of the interpolated values on the same graph including the a, b, and the cosine curve. I keep getting error of having the interpolated values having different lengths.

Comment: `plot(x,y1,x,y2,x,y3,x,y4);hold on;plot(a,b);`

Comment: You can also plot the samples from the last graph. `...; hold on; plot(a,b,'*')` .